# Connection between integer lattice and quadratic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, integer-lattices

I read from http://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Prizes/2014/news_release_bhargava.pdf

"If one has a quadratic polynomial, counting the number
of integer lattice points in a certain region of 3-dimensional space provides
information about the associated quadratic number field."

My questions are

1. Suppose polynomial is $ax^2+bx+c$, what is the corresponding
   lattice?
2. Which region one should try to get information?

   3.What kind of information one will get?

Comment: See books like [thisone](http://people.math.umass.edu/~bates/Primes_of_the_form.pdf) about primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$, (binary) quadratic forms, and lattices in $\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{C}$ and quadratic number fields. For $n = 5$, the polynomial $x^2+5 y^2$ is associated to the lattice $L = \{ (x,y \sqrt{5}) \in \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2\}$ and $x^2+5y^2 = \|(x,y \sqrt{5})\|^2$. It is also associated to $\{ x+i y \sqrt{5}, (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \}$ a subring of the imaginary quadratic number field $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{5})$.